# blueimp jquery file upload done callback not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, blueimp

I am using blueimp jquery fileupload pluging to upload image to server it is working absolutely fine on desktop on all the browsers but its not working on mobile
I dont know is there anything I have to do extra to upload file in mobile devices
My code is

```js
$('#Add_image').fileupload({
        dataType: 'text',
        url: ImageUploadURL,
        dropZone: $('.image-upload '),
        singleFileUploads: false,
        limitMultiFileUploads: 8,
        autoUpload: true,
        add: function(e, data) {
            var valid = true;
            if($('#uploaded-images li').length>=8)
            {
                alert('You can not upload more than 8 Images');
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                var re = /^.+\.((jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)|(gif)|(bmp))$/i;
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    if (!re.test(file.name)) {
                        alert('Only jpg, png, gif and bmp image files are allowed');
                        valid = false;
                    }
                });
            }
            if (valid) {
                $('.progress-bar-container').show();
                data.url = ImageUploadURL+'&remove='+RemoveImage;
                data.submit();
            }
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data=$.parseJSON(data.result);
            if(data.Status)
            {
                if(data.RemovePrevious)
                {
                    $('#uploaded-images').empty();
                }
                $(data.Result).each(function(i,v){
                    $('#uploaded-images').append('<li data-imageid="'+v.ImageID+'"><img src="'+v.ImagePath+'?r='+Math.random()+'"/>'+
                        '<a class="remove-uploaded-image" data-imageid="'+v.ImageID+'" data-imagename="'+v.ImageName+'">Remove</a></li>');
                    if(data.RemovePrevious)
                    {
                        RemoveImage=v.ImageName;
                    }
                });
                if($('#uploaded-images li').length>=8)
                {
                    $('.image-file-upload-buttons').hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.image-file-upload-buttons').show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Oops');
            }
            return;
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                            
        setTimeout(function(e){
            $('.progress-value').text(progress+'%');
            $('.progress-bar').css('width',progress+'%');},100);

        if(progress==100)
        {
            setTimeout(function(e){
                $('.progress-bar').hide();
                setTimeout(function(e){
                    $('.progress-bar').css('width','0%');
                    $('.progress-value').text('0%');
                    $('.progress-bar').show();
                    $('.progress-bar-container').hide();
                },100);
            },1000);
        }
    })
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but here's a solution.

go to jquery.fileupload-ui.js

look for autoupload and change it to true from false.